# Selenium with PHP timeout

Tags: php, selenium, curl

I have a couple of selenium tests written in PHP.

Since yesterday one test keeps timing out with a simple $webdriver->get($url);
This is happening in like 80% of the executions.

It takes like 5 minutes to finish the request. When i open the url in the browser (same browser, without selenium) the page is loading imediately.

Selenium standalone-server, chromedriver and chrome are up to date.

Does anyone know this issue?

Comment: It seems this only happens on pages containing a reCaptcha. (i do not need to solve them of course, the validation is disabled on test environments)